# Millisecond precision in syslogd on OS X

Tags: macos, timestamp, syslog, syslogd

When I log messages to syslog in OS X (10.10.1), it truncates the timestamp to the second. If I log to a file, for example, I am able to capture milliseconds. Milliseconds matter when logs are coming fast and furiously. Any idea if there’s a way to set millisecond precision in the OS X implementation of syslogd?

Comment: Did you read the `syslog(1)` man page? It gives examples of how to do this.

Comment: Yes, and `syslogd`. I don't see anything there on precision of timestamps. Is there a specific section you could point me to? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was on mobile last night and just wanted to quickly set you down the right path. Fuller answer below.

Answer (score 0):

OS X's `syslogd` stores log events in the "Apple System Log" (asl) database/store with microsecond precision by default, with provisions for nanosecond precision.

However, when that data gets copied out into traditional flat log files like `/var/log/system.log`, the traditional to-the-second timestamp format are used, because that's what those flat log files have always used.

You can use the `syslog` command-line tool to query the asl database, and you can specify the format of the output with various command-line options including `-F`. For example, to dump everything from the asl database in standard log file format, but with microsecond precision, do this:

```
syslog -F std.6
```

Note that if you have a process logging so many messages to syslog so fast that sub-second timestamps matter, you might want to also look at the `asl.conf(5)` man page to make sure your `mps_limit` and `dup_delay` parameters are set in such a way that all your log messages actually get stored in the database, as opposed to being throttled or thrown out.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I'm building a syslog server that listens for syslog messages over UDP. It doesn't sound like there's a way to change the timestamp precision of the messages flowing through syslogd on an OS X client (i.e. upstream pushing messages to my server). asl looks like it has more config options, but I don't really understand the relationship between syslog and asl and I don't see anything about time precision in asl either.

Comment: @JustinMakeig The traditional syslog network protocol (by which hosts can send syslog messages via UDP to a central syslog server), which was created decades ago in one of the earliest BSD Unixes, has a timestamp field that only has to-the-second precision. This protocol was eventually documented in Informational RFC 3164. This is the syslog protocol OS X supports. There was an effort in the IETF in 2009 to create a modernized version of the syslog protocol (including more timestamp precision) and standardize it (RFC 5424), but I don't believe OS X's syslog supports the modern version.

Comment: Yes, and RFC 3164 specifies "Mmm dd hh:mm:ss". Looks like I'm out of luck. Thanks so much for your help.